# Asking my coworker his/her scale of success for a person

Tags: colleagues, personal-questions

One day I asked a coworker "What his/her scale for a successful person?" Usually we have side chat in private teams chat but he/she didn't respond to my question and by end of the day, I deleted the message and apologized. Why did I ask him/her? Because he/she is a team lead and I want to become a team lead.
I want to ask is what I did wrong? Or am I in trouble?

Comment: I don't understand "but his/her response to my message and by end of day I delete the message and apologize". Does this mean "the coworker did not respond to me, so I deleted the message"?

Comment: yes I correct sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question was so generic, it might have taken several hours for your coworker to write out a good answer.

Instead of asking them such a generic question like that over chat, be more direct about your underlying objective. Tell them you want to eventually become a team lead yourself and you'd like their advice on how you could possibly achieve that goal.

Then ask to schedule a meeting with them to discuss this particular topic. Having a face-to-face meeting (even if it's over Skype) would make it a lot easier for them to answer this kind of question.

Also, giving them the exact topic and scheduling such a meeting well in advance (perhaps in one or two weeks) would give them plenty of time to think about the topic in advance.